# installing Gevent on OSX

Tags: python, django, sockets

```
>>> import gevent
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/gevent/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/gevent/core.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/gevent/core.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/admin/.python-eggs/gevent-0.13.6-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg-tmp/gevent/core.so, 2): Symbol not found: _event_global_current_base_
  Referenced from: /Users/admin/.python-eggs/gevent-0.13.6-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg-tmp/gevent/core.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/admin/.python-eggs/gevent-0.13.6-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg-tmp/gevent/core.so
```

What's this about? I did not get any errors during the installation

Answer (score 3):

fixed for github

**Libevent**

First I like to grab libevent via macports. Ignore this if you’ve already done it on your system.

```
sudo ports install libevent
```

Alternatively you could build it yourself or use Homebrew. By the way, both MacPorts and Homebrew do use the newer Libevent2.X.X branch.

**Install cython**

```
pip install cython
```

**Install greenlet** (optional as gevent will build this).

```
pip install greenlet
```

**Clone, Build, Install gevent.**

```
git clone https://github.com/gevent/gevent.git
```

I like to first build gevent to see if everything went right. Change to the gevent directory first and then:

```
python setup.py build
```

If all went well go ahead and install:

```
python setup.py install
```